# How to access metastore of Hive in Spark java program in maven?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I wrote a maven project in Java to store some hive tables using spark. The tables and metasore are in the directories `spark-warehouse` and `metastore_db` in my eclipse workspace. The locations of `spark-warehouse` and `metastore_db` are `/Users/username/workspace/Spark-Hive/load/spark-warehouse` and `/Users/username/workspace/Spark-Hive/load/metastore_db`

I wrote another maven project to access those hive tables using the following spark session:

```
    String warehouseLocation = "/Users/username/workspace/Spark-Hive/load/spark-warehouse";
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Load")
                .master("local[*]")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
//      .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/Users/username/workspace/Spark-Hive/load/metastore_db")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
```

I am able to access those tables from my first maven project that I wrote to load tables, but could not access the tables from my second maven project. I also gave the path of hive metastore to the second program but did not work. How can I access those hive tables in eclipse using maven project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `spark-warehouse` path in the following way:

```
String warehouseLocation = new File("/Users/username/workspace/Spark-Hive/load/spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath();
```